# How to connect a button to a function in another spreadsheet in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in google sheets and I made a code where you add some data in a cell and click a button (which I already created in the spreadsheet) and the code will do some calculations. All of that works perfectly, the problem is that I don't want the code to be in the same spreadsheet because I don't want people to see it, so I created a new spreadsheet and added the code there and the answer or the calculations can be send to the first spreadsheet, I'll call this new spreadsheet as S2 and the first spreadsheet as S1. So the code is in S2 and the button is in S1. I added a button in S2 just to see if the code worked and if it would send the calculations to S1 and it worked perfectly as well. The only thing I can't do is that the button in S1 could call the function that makes everything in S2. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please break down the question into a few paragraphs or steps it is a bit hard to read like this. You could also have a screenshot or a graphic that explains what you want.

Comment: Srry, I'll do that next question. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script on the Spreadsheets "S2" by clicking a button on the Spreadsheet "S1".

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, a Google Apps Script library is used. At first, add the version to the script on "S2". Then, the script assigned to the button on "S1" uses the script on "S2" as the library. By this, you can use the script on "S2" by clicking the button on "S1".

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Web Apps is used. At first, deploy Web Apps with the script on "S2". In this case, `doGet` might be suitable. Then, the script assigned to the button on "S1" uses the script on "S2" by requesting to Web Apps with `UrlFetchApp`. By this, you can use the script on "S2" by clicking the button on "S1".

#### References:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: @Add Thank you for your response.